# Mirror FBX animation in Three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, fbx

Is there any way to mirror FBX animation in Three.js?
I already have boxer animations and now I need to made a mirrored clone of each to realize both sides stands.
I know that I can do it in Blender or another program but I wanna reduce my app size.

Comment: Please elaborate. It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish with such little info. Maybe some images would help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have my animations in .fbx files. They are animations of boxing motions. In box there are two stands: for right-handed and left-handed people. I want to load my "right-handed" animations, then copy each and mirror it, so I could have 2 animation instances (original and mirrored) for each motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I forgot to post an answer :) So the answer to my question is to apply scale matrix.

For example, if you want to mirror model by X-axis, you need to multiply its position by scale matrix with coefficients (-1, 1, 1). Also you need to multiply position along X-axis and rotation around Y-axis by negative one to prevent side transformation.

Here's some THREE.js code:

```
this.model.position.x *= -1.0;
this.model.rotation.y *= -1.0;
this.model.applyMatrix4(new Matrix4().makeScale(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
```